# How do I make a textbox readonly only for a specific MVC Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, razorengine

The title might be confusing, so here is my problem:
I'd like in my View a readonly textbox only if my Action is for editing (something like EditLocation) and if my Action is intended for adding a new record (AddLocation), I'd like an editable textbox.

My ff. code works, but I was wondering if there's a "cleaner" solution

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(Model.Location.Id == 0 ? "AddLocation" : "EditLocation", "Location"))
    {
        <fieldset>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Location.Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Location.CompanyGroupId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CompanyGroup.Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CompanyGroup.Code)

            <div class="form-group">
                <strong><span>@ResourcesCommon.Location_Code</span></strong>
                @if (Model.Location.Id == 0)
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Location.Code, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Location.Code)
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Location.Code, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Location.Code)
                }

            </div> ...
```

Thanks and have a good week ahead!

Comment: One option would be to create your own `HtmlHelper` extension methods ([refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482305/access-model-class-instance-from-a-custom-additionalmetadataattribute-asp-net-m/26483022#26483022) for an example), but really, you should be using 2 views (and make use of partials for common html)

Comment: I totally agree with creating two separate views, but the owner of the application wants a single View for reusability purposes.

Comment: Seriously? Its a maintenance nightmare and difficult to debug. If they want reusability, then make use of partials for the common parts of the views.

Comment: I agree, voted your comment up :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Location.Code, new Dictionary<string, object>()
                                   .AddIf(true, "@class", "form-control")
                                    .AddIf(Model.Location.Id != 0, "@readonly", "readonly"))`

```
// This returns the dictionary so that you can "fluently" add values
    public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> AddIf<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, bool addIt, TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (addIt)
            dictionary.Add(key, value);
        return dictionary;
    }
```

I took it from another stackoverflow post long back which i don't have the link.

Comment: This is interesting, gonna try it.

Comment: If you found it interesting; if it was helpful and if you find it as a "cleaner" solution, please don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (but it will produce more code):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Location.Code, new { @class = "form-control", @id="myInput" })
```

and then add some js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myInput').attr('readonly', @Html.Raw(Model.Location.Id != 0? "true" : "false"));
});
```